# How to open your project/app in the Android AVD? I want to test my app

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

My AVD works fine and shows the homescreen and menu and everything but how to open my app/project in it?

Comment: the same way you would open any other app ... click on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Eclipse IDE for your development, hit Run as... -> Android Application, select as Target the AVD you've created already and click Run.

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I asked such a noobish question :P

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is from `Eclipse IDE`.

See [**Building and Running from Eclipse with ADT**](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-eclipse.html#RunConfig)

It is all explained clearly.